# Pass Variable from View to Partial View with @Html.Partial Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have code like this:

```
<div id="SettingsTabPanel" class="tabbable-line" style="padding-top:20px;">
 <div id="ProjectTimeLine" class="tab-pane">
   @{ var test = 10;}
   @test
 </div>
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/PortfolioResearch/Partials/_LabUtilization.cshtml")
</div>
```

in `_LabUtilization.cshtml`, I call variable test like this `@test`. But There is error because @test undefined. What should I do to call variable `test` in `_LabUtilization.cshtml` ?

Comment: Use a viewmodel should help for this purpose. You can try `RenderPartial` and passing viewmodel containing `Test` property assigned with certain value.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto, sorry i am newbie, can you give me the example using `RenderPartial`?

Comment: @zuckerburg, you should give me link reference which related with my problem after your comment

Comment: @AghnatAtqiya Literally any MVC tutorial will guide you with this, that is why I felt it didn't need a link? I guess someone with more time on their hands can write out an entire tutorial for you as an answer, but this isn't the point of the site. Sorry I couldn't help guide you

Answer (score 0):

User some model to send value to partial, like this

```
//your model
public class SomeModel
{
   public string test {get;set;}
}

//you view
@model SomeModel
<div id="SettingsTabPanel" class="tabbable-line" style="padding-top:20px;">
 <div id="ProjectTimeLine" class="tab-pane">
   @{ var test = 10;
Model.test = test;
}
   @test
 </div>
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/PortfolioResearch/Partials/_LabUtilization.cshtml", Model)
</div>


//your _LabUtilization partial

@model SomeModel

<span> @Model.test</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdullah Hunzai, but I want passing variabel from view to other view without change my model

Comment: You are welcome! if that is the case then you can use TempData["yourKeyName"] = "some value"; like this assign value in first view and get value from from temp data in the second view. like: var anyVariable = (Type)TempData["yourKeyName"]; I hope this will work.